# How do I move cursor around on unix shell using VIM commands?

Tags: command-line, unix

I'm a vim user and forgot to grab my csh/vim settings before leaving my prev company.

Basically, when tooling around my unix shell, I used vim commands (eg go back and forth using VIM quick-keys, using 'b', using 'w', etc).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about your shell and not about Vi or Vim (See [the help center](https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about csh specifically, but for sh, ksh, and Bash, `set -o vi`, and for Zsh I think `bindkey -v`. You can add that to your `~/.profile` or whatever. You can also add this to your `~/inputrc`:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-command
```

for all programs that use Readline (including Bash).